# A strange PHP object

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm using SimpleXML to get some data from an API. Its returning things in this format:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

My question is, how can I possibly access the string value of this object? If I try to do `$myVariable->0` that gives me an error. Doing `$zero = '0'` and then `echo $myVariable->$zero` doesn't work either, nor does `(array) $myVariable` work (that gives a warning).

Comment: @Nem cheers bro, that worked. Post answer and i'll accept :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is that `SimpleXMLElement` has [`__toString`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) magic method implemented that would return your `string(36) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`, so to get this string you just cast (string) on your `SimpleXMLElement` object:

```
(string)$myVariable
```

With `PHP` you can

```
print $myVariable;
```

of course, so explicit `(string)` here is not necessarily needed.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR it's like this:

```
$myVariable->{0}
```

---

Edit: That would work in majority of cases, but not this one. It looks like SimpleXML implements not only `__toString` method like Nemoden pointed out, but also `__get`, so that accessing object properties in this way results in cloned object being returned.

Comment: Strange. I've just tested it with `StdClass` object, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Must be something to do with SimpleXML, It returns an empty SimpleXML object when I do that.

Comment: Indeed. It looks like it's recursively cloning itself when accessed in this way.